# Check all Checkboxes checked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

My HTML Dom like the followings:

```
<div class="menu">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk-act">
   <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk-act">
   <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk-act">
</div>


<div class="menu">
   <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk-act">
   <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk-act">
   <input type="checkbox" value="6" class="chk-act">
   <input type="checkbox" value="7" class="chk-act">
</div>



<div class="menu">
   <input type="checkbox" value="8" class="chk-act">
   <input type="checkbox" value="9" class="chk-act">
</div>
```

The number of Checkboxes is not fixed in each `div`. That can be 1 up to 50. So I need to check in each `div` if all checkboxes checked then some changes in div style like changed the color, what is your suggestion to check all checkboxes checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line:

```
$('.menu:has(:checkbox:not(:checked))');
```

To explain, this will select all the `<div class="menu">` elements which have inside them a checkbox which hasn't been checked. You could then add a css class or do whatever you need. If you needed to 'reset' them after adding a class, I'd do something like this:

```
$('.menu')
    .removeClass('notChecked')
    .filter(':has(:checkbox:not(:checked))')
    .addClass('notChecked');
```